# The equivalent to a content script in a Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am quite new to Firefox and its extensions. Is there something like a script using JavaScript that runs every time a page loads? My chrome extension injects a css file creating a link tag using js. How do I port this to Firefox?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the [pageMod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) API.

```
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.example.org",
  contentScript: 'window.alert("Page matches ruleset");'
});
```

Comment: In what page do I put this? A js file included in the browser.xul perhaps?

Comment: @JacquesBlom: You put it into `lib/main.js` for an extension built with the [Add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/builder).

Comment: That isn't a valid match pattern: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.4/packages/api-utils/docs/match-pattern.html

Comment: This link no longer works.  You now want https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/util/match-pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mozIJSSubScriptLoader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/mozIJSSubScriptLoader) to execute the JavaScript ***(chrome://myExtension/content/script.js)*** every time a [webpage loads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/On_page_load). Here is the sample code that you need to modify according to your chrome directory

```
window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){
    window.removeEventListener("load", load, false); //remove listener, no longer needed
    myExtension.init();  
},false);

var myExtension = {
  init: function() {
    var appcontent = document.getElementById("appcontent");   // browser
    if(appcontent){
      appcontent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myExtension.onPageLoad, true);
    }
    var messagepane = document.getElementById("messagepane"); // mail
    if(messagepane){
      messagepane.addEventListener("load", function(event) { myExtension.onPageLoad(event); }, true);
    }
  },

  onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {
    var doc = aEvent.originalTarget; // doc is document that triggered "onload" event
    // do something with the loaded page.
    // doc.location is a Location object (see below for a link).
    // You can use it to make your code executed on certain pages only.
    var loader = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/moz/jssubscript-loader;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.mozIJSSubScriptLoader);
              loader.loadSubScript("chrome://myExtension/content/script.js", doc); 

    // add event listener for page unload 
    aEvent.originalTarget.defaultView.addEventListener("unload", function(event){ myExtension.onPageUnload(event); }, true);
  },

  onPageUnload: function(aEvent) {
    // do something
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to use Greasemonkey on Firefox.  In fact, Chrome Extensions began as a mimic of Greasemonkey, and were the origin of content scripts.